# Converting data from one class to another

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wcf, combobox

I'm trying to convert data from one *ExtensionMethods* class to another class called *ComboBoxViewItem*

**ExtensionMethods**:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int GetDisplayItemId(this ComboBox combobox)
    {
        if (combobox.SelectedItem == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return ((DisplayItems)combobox.SelectedItem).Id; //Error here
    }
}
```

**ComboBoxViewItem**

```
class ComboBoxViewItem<T>
{
    private string name;
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxViewItem(T item, string name)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ComboBoxViewItem(T item)
    {
        var prop = item.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
        if (prop == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("This object does not have a Name property, please use the other contructor.");
        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            throw new ArgumentException("The property Name MUST be of type string. Please use the other contructor instead.");
        this.Item = item;
        this.name = (string)prop.GetValue(item);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Step 1** Now what I'm trying to do is load data from my WCF service into one of my comboboxes like this:

```
public async Task LoadCompanies()
{
    using (MKCServiceClient service = new MKCServiceClient())
    {
        var companies = await service.GetCompaniesAsync();
        foreach (var company in companies)
            cmbQuoteCompany.Items.Add(new ComboBoxViewItem<Company>(company));
        cmbQuoteCompany.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
} //Coding works fine and loads data into the combobox
```

**Step 2** I want to add that data that was selected in the combobox to be added else where in another table using this method below:

```
private async void btnQuoteAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (MKCServiceClient service = new MKCServiceClient())
    {
        quoteInformation = await service.GetQuoteAsync(new QuoteData
        {
            CompanyId = cmbQuoteCompany.GetDisplayItemId(), //I use ExtensionMethods class here
            BranchId = cmbQuoteBranch.GetDisplayItemId(), //Here
            CustomerId = cmbQuoteContact.GetDisplayItemId(), //Here
            CustomerRFQ = txtQuoteCustomerRFQ.Text,
            Date = dpQuoteDate.Text,
            Item = txtQuoteItem.Text,
            Material = txtQuoteMaterial.Text,
            Description = txtQuoteDescription.Text,
            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuoteQTY.Text)
        });

        await service.FinalizeQuoteAsync(finalizeQuote);
    }
}
```

My end goal is to get the *Id* of the selected item in my combobox and then insert it into my database.

After I call the *btnQuoteAdd_Click* method, my application crashes and gives me the following error

> *Unable to cast object of type
>   'MKCWorkflowApplication.ComboBoxViewItem`1[MKCWorkflowApplication.WorkflowService.Company]'
>   to type 'MKCWorkflowApplication.DisplayItems'.*

The reason why i'm posting this issue here is because i've been given this coding from a friend who knows a lot more that C# than me and we are no longer in contact, so I don't know how to get past this issue :( 
So if anyone could figure out what is going on, please help! Thank you.

Comment: Your extension method GetDisplayItemID expects a combobox filled with DisplayItem instances not filled with ComboBoxViewItem<T> and thus the internal cast fails. A possible workaround could be written if your classes Company, Quote and Branch provide a similar property named ID. What are the definitions of these classes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The Company, Branch and Customer classes are the tables that I get the data from, so all four of them do have Id's in them as their primary keys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension method `GetDisplayItemID` expects a combobox filled with instances of the class`DisplayItem` not filled with instances of a ComboBoxViewItem and thus the internal cast fails. A possible workaround could be written if your classes Company, Quote and Customer provide an indentical named property `ID`.

You could rewrite your `ComboBoxViewItem<T>` class in this way

```
class ComboBoxViewItem<T>
{
    public string Name;
    public int ID;
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxViewItem(T item, string name, int id)
    {
        this.Item = item;
        this.Name = name;
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public ComboBoxViewItem(T item)
    {
        var prop = item.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
        if (prop == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("This object does not have ...");
        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            throw new ArgumentException("The property Name MUST be of type...");
        this.Name = (string)prop.GetValue(item);
        prop = item.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
        if (prop == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("This object does not have ...");
        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(int))
            throw new ArgumentException("The property ID MUST be of ...");
        this.ID = (int)prop.GetValue(item);
        this.Item = item;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // C# 6.0 string interpolation
        //return string.Format($"{ID}, ({Name})");

        // C# Standard string formatting
        return string.Format("{0}, ({1})", ID, Name);
    }
}
```

Now you could retrieve the ID from your comboboxes using this syntax without using the old extension method or defining a new one.

```
CustomerId = (cmbQuoteContact.SelectedItem as ComboBoxViewItem<Customer>).Item.ID
....
```

Comment: About your edit. This $ is supposed to be used in C# 6.0 string interpolation functionality. If you remove it you should use the normal approach. Without it you get a format error if you call ToString. Wondering why has been approved.

Comment: If I leave the $ in there and use the c# 6.0 approach, I get an error saying: *) expected*. I thought it was a type, sorry. I am getting *Input string is not in correct format* when I call btnQuoteAdd_Click though?